# Using RequiredFieldValidator WITHOUT server-side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx page with a form on it. The form has 6 fields and a "NEXT" button. Clicking the "NEXT" button slides away the current form, and slides in a new one using jquery.

When you click the next button, the form is validated and the errors are displayed as intended. However, upon validation without any client-side errors, the page then does a postback. This postback causes the slider-form to be reset to the first slide.

Is there a way to make it so the next button solely does client-side validation, thus disabling postback? (I plan on doing server-side postback when the final form is submitted.)

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="input" ID="exampleTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="rfvexampleTextBox" ControlToValidate="exampleTextBox" ErrorMessage="Please enter a value" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="slide1" />
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="continuebutton" Text="NEXT" ValidationGroup="slide1"></asp:Button>
```

I've tried messing with the `useSubmitBehavior=false` attribute to no avail.

I've also tried `onClientclick="return false;"`, but this performs no validation at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the attribute `CausesValidation` as `true` like:

```
  <asp:Button Text="sample"
                    CausesValidation="True"
                    runat="server"/>
```

> When it is **true** the validation is performed when the Button control is clicked;

Comment: CausesValidation is true by default though, no?